# Как вызвать метод из другого скрипта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу создать игру, где нужно стрелять по воздушным шарикам. В игре должен быть реализован выбор оружия, из предлагаемого игрой. В зависимости от выбранного оружия должно меняться кол-во патронов, что имеется у игрока, а так же скорость стрельбы и прицел.
Для этого теоретически **необходимо, чтоб вызывался один и тот же метод у дочернего элемента**("Weapon" к примеру), в следствии из-за смены оружия будет меняться и его параметры.
**Как это возможно реализовать в юнити?**
Желательно, чтоб все делалось в коде, без вмешательства инспектора. Я не знаю, возможно ли это, но если возможно, то хотел бы реализовать именно так.

Comment: Для этого и придумано ООП, в частности наследование. Разное оружие нужно наследовать от общего класса, у которого и будет этот метод.

Comment: Если в WindowsFroms я просто пишу "class MyForm : Form, MyClass", и в дальнейшем в коде могу апкастить "MyClass newForm = new MyForm()" и использовать методы, что наследует форма, то в Unity как это реализовать - я не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать абстрактный класс для этих самых видов оружия, допустим Weapon.
Каждый вид оружия наследовать от этого класса, например, class Javelin : Weapon.
И в нём реализовать нужный Вам метод.

Или же виртуальный класс Weapon, в котором прописать реализацию изначально, а в наследниках переопределять, если потребуется.